# Why the following operands could not be broadcasted together?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, array-broadcasting

The arrays are of following dimensions:
`dists`: (500,5000)
`train`: (5000,)
`test`:(500,)

Why does the first two statements throw an error whereas the third one works fine?

1. `dists += train + test`

Error: `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5000,) (500,)`

2. `dists += train.reshape(-1,1) + test.reshape(-1,1)`

Error: `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5000,1) (500,1)`

3. `dists += train + test.reshape(-1,1)`
   This works fine!

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's to do with NumPy's broadcasting rules. Quoting the NumPy manual:

> When operating on two arrays, NumPy compares their shapes element-wise. It starts with the trailing dimensions, and works its way forward. Two  dimensions are compatible when
>
> 1. they are equal, or
> 2. one of them is 1

The first statement throws an error because NumPy looks at the only dimension, and `(5000,)` and `(500,)` are inequal and cannot be broadcast together.

In the second statement, `train.reshape(-1,1)` has the shape `(5000,1)` and `test.reshape(-1,1)` has the shape `(500,1)`. The trailing dimension (length one) is equal, so that's ok, but then NumPy checks the other dimension and `5000 != 500`, so the broadcasting fails here.

In the third case, your operands are `(5000,)` and `(500,1)`. In this case NumPy *does* allow broadcasting. The 1D-array is extended along the trailing length-1 dimension of the 2D-array.

FWIW, the shape and broadcasting rules can be a bit tricky sometimes, and I've often been confused with similar matters.

Comment: Is it the case that because both of them are 1 it needed to check if they were equal, but when ONLY one of them is 1 it doesn't need to check for equality?

Comment: It needs to check every dimension for compatibility. In the second case 1 and 1 are compatible, but 5000 and 500 are not. In the third case 5000 and 1 are compatible, and there are no more dimensions to check.