# Why I can not calculate distance between two numpy array?

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

1.I had two numpy arrays which are data_test and data_train respectively

```
    data_partial_test = data_test[:2000,:]
    test_lable = label_test
    print(test_lable.shape)
    print(data_partial_test[0].shape)
    print(data_train[0].shape)
    dis = (( data_partial_test- data_train[:21000,])**2).sum(axis=1)
```

2.The shape of data_test is (21000,784) and the shape of data_train is(2000,784). When I run this code it said :operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2000,784) (21000,784)

Comment: What is your expected result here? Numpy will try to subtract the values element-wise, but since the shapes are different that is not possible. Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50758165/why-the-following-operands-could-not-be-broadcasted-together/50758844

Comment: My expected result would be the distance between these two NumPy array

Comment: I understand. A simple example to illustrate the problem here: if you have `a = [1,2,3,4,5]` and `b = [1,2]`, and then try to take `a-b` then it won't work (which element should be subtracted with which in this case?). If the shapes are the same, then it element-wise subtraction would work, for example: `a=[1,2]`, `b=[1,2]`, `a-b=[0,0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you perform **arrays subtraction**, like *arr_1 - arr_2*,
then actually *Numpy* attempts:

- to subtract elements of row *0* in *arr_2* from corresponding elements
  of *arr_1* (also in row *0*),
- the same for row *1*,
- and so on, up to the end of both arrays.

This scheme works as long as both arrays have **the same** number of rows
and columns.

There are 3 exceptions to this rule:

- One of arrays involved can have a **single row**. Then this row is
  **broadcast** (repeated) so that this array has conceptually as many
  rows as needed.
- One of arrays involved can have a **single column**. Then the
  broadcasting mentioned above takes place along **columns**.
- One of operands is a **single value**. Then it is "expanded" to an array
  with the number of rows / columns like in the other operand (array).

Read about broadcasting in *Numpy* to have more detailed view on this.

In your case no of the above sitiations takes place.
Both arrays have the same number of columns, but the number of rows is
**different**.
The consequence is that the above broadcasting can not be performed and the whole
operation fails.

**Possible solution**

Maybe each row in the first array (with smaller number of rows) can be
"paired up" with a row in the second array, e.g. based on some key field.
Such operation can be performed in *Pandas*. See for *join* method in *Pandas*.

Then you can:

- convert your both *Numpy* arrays to *pandasonic* DataFrames,
- perform a **join** on these DataFrames (based on a common key, usually
  set to the index in each DataFrame),
- compute differences between proper pairs of columns.

Then you can:

- square these differences,
- sum them up,
- and finally compute the root of the sum, getting the wanted distance.